# How can I get the list of VM Sizes I can use when creating a HDInsight Cluster

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-hdinsight

Given c# .net 4.5.2, When creating a HDInsight Cluster, How do I know sizes I can use for my head/worker node in my region?

In the portal I get A3, A4, A6, A7, A10, A11, D3, D4, D12, D13 and D14
https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.HDInsightCluster

In Powershell I get
**North Europe** A10, A11, A5, A6, A7, A8, A9, Basic_A0, Basic_A1, Basic_A2, Basic_A3, Basic_A4, ExtraLarge, ExtraSmall, Large, Medium, Small, Standard_D1, Standard_D1_v2, Standard_D11, Standard_D11_v2, Standard_D12, Standard_D12_v2, Standard_D13, Standard_D13_v2, Standard_D14, Standard_D14_v2, Standard_D2, Standard_D2_v2, Standard_D3, Standard_D3_v2, Standard_D4, Standard_D4_v2, Standard_D5_v2, Standard_DS1, Standard_DS11, Standard_DS12, Standard_DS13, Standard_DS14, Standard_DS2, Standard_DS3, Standard_DS4
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-size-specs/

What API call should I be used to get the available HDInsights I can create?

Note; This is using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.HDInsight, Version=1.5.12.0 as the latest Microsoft.Azure.Management.HDInsight, is in preview

```
             var clusterInfo = new ClusterCreateParametersV2
             {
                Name = clusterConfig.ClusterName,
                Location = clusterConfig.Location,
                DefaultStorageAccountName = clusterConfig.StorageAccount.StorageAccountName,
                DefaultStorageAccountKey = clusterConfig.StorageAccount.StorageAccountKey,
                DefaultStorageContainer = _storageConfiguration.Containers.HDInsightInstance,
                UserName = clusterConfig.UserName,
                Password = clusterConfig.Password,
                ClusterSizeInNodes = clusterConfig.ClusterSize,
                Version = clusterConfig.Version,
                HeadNodeSize = clusterConfig.NodeSize,
                DataNodeSize = clusterConfig.NodeSize,
            };
```

```

Comment: Are you looking for an answer using the Microsoft.Azure.Management.HDInsight  SDK or Azure PowerShell will do?

Comment: C# SDK. Do you know how to do it in PowerShell out of interest?

Comment: Looks like `$x = Get-AzureRmHDInsightProperties` might help `$x.VmSizes.Values`

Answer (score 0):

In c#, With the "Microsoft.Azure.Management.HDInsight" version="1.1.0"

```
var location = "North Europe";
using (var client = new HDInsightManagementClient(AzureActiveDirectory.GetTokenCloudCredentials(SubscriptionId)))
{
    var response = await client.Clusters.GetCapabilitiesAsync(location);
    var sizes = response.VmSizes["iaas"].AvailableVmSizes.ToArray()
};
    }
```

iaas or paas